# Expecting '}' but was: 'for'

Tags: apex

```
public class ActivateServiceResources {

  list<user> lstuser = [Select id,IsActive from user where IsActive = True];
  list<ServiceResource> lstservice = [select id,RelatedRecordid,Isactive from serviceresource where RelatedRecordid IN:lstuser];

list<serviceresource> SRlist = new list<serviceresource>();

for (serviceresource SR:lstservice)
    {
        if (SR.Isactive != True)
            {
                SR.Isactive = True;
                SRlist.add(SR);
            }
    }

update SRlist;

}
```

Comment: please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the logic inside the method. You can not put the logic directly in the class. Try below code

```
public class ActivateServiceResources {

  public void yourMethodName(){
      list<user> lstuser = [Select id,IsActive from user where IsActive = True];
  list<ServiceResource> lstservice = [select id,RelatedRecordid,Isactive from serviceresource where RelatedRecordid IN:lstuser];

list<serviceresource> SRlist = new list<serviceresource>();

for (serviceresource SR:lstservice)
    {
        if (SR.Isactive != True)
            {
                SR.Isactive = True;
                SRlist.add(SR);
            }
    }

update SRlist;
  }

}
```